# Vue.js Google / Microsoftgraph login

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

[image]I have a Laravel app and I am using vue.js and vue-authenticate to have a user login with their Microsoft account.  The vue.js app is living under a laravel route not Laravel home page i.e. if the homepage route is / then the vueapp route is /vueapp.

On the vueapp's home page I have the Login with Microsoft button configured. In my vue app the base url is set to  mydomain/vueapp.   I can successfully authorize the app with my Microsoft account but then instead of being able to see a success message and a token, I see the following error:

Error: Request failed with status code 405

I have Axios and Vuex installed and my vue routes are supported in the hash mode instead of history because of some weird laravel issue.

Update:  I am seeing a similar issue with Google.  It seems like something happens when the URI is redirected.

Update: Below is my code:

For my component:

```
<script>
import store from '../store'
import axios from 'axios'
export default{
data () {
  return {
  }
},
methods: {
    authenticate: function (provider) {
    console.log("Login Started" + provider);
    this.$auth.authenticate(provider).then((response) => {
    console.log("Login Successful " + response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("error occured ");
    console.log(error);

        })
}

},
}
</script>
```

My HTML ---

auth Live
   auth Google

In my app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import lodash from 'lodash'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import VueAuthenticate from 'vue-authenticate'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(VueLodash, lodash)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
import vmodal from 'vue-js-modal'
Vue.use(vmodal, {
dialog: true,
dynamic: true,
})
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';
Vue.use(Toasted,  'top-center')
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(Vuex)


import VueAuthenticate from 'vue-authenticate'
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
baseUrl: 'https://www.mywebsite.com', // Your API domain

providers: {
live: {

  clientId: 'My Mcirosoft key',
  redirectUri: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/auth/live' // Your client app URL
},
google: {

  clientId: 'mygooglekey.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  redirectUri: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/auth/google' 
}
}
})
```

In laravel - I have the following routes.  Webapp is the folder where vue app lives and it uses the hash mode for routing not history.

```
 Route::get('webapp/{path?}', function () {
 return View::make('app');
 })->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
 Route::get('auth/live', function () {
 return View::make('app');
 });
 Route::get('auth/google', function () {
 return View::make('app');
 });
```

Comment: How can you authorize the app if you get a 405? Can you post more information about the error?

Comment: @HelderLucas I can authorize the app with Microsoft - error occurs during the callback.  I have updated the original post with an image.